# Correct management of addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I'm still new to blocks in objective-c and wondering if I have this psuedo code correct. I'm not sure if it's enough to just remove the observer or if i have to call removeObserver:name:object:

```
-(void) scan {
    Scanner *scanner = [[Scanner alloc] init];
    id scanComplete = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ScanComplete" 
                        object:scanner 
                        queue:nil 
                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
                            /*
                             do something
                             */
                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:scanComplete];
                            [scanner release];
                        }];
    [scanner startScan];
}
```

Update: I'm receiving intermittent `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from this block, so this can't be right.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Declare the `scanComplete` variable before defining the block itself.

The reason why you need to do this is because you're trying to access a variable that doesn't exist within the block at the time of definition since the variable itself has not been assigned yet.

What is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Well, it's an exception that is thrown when you try to access a reference that doesn't exist. So that is exactly the case in your example.

So if you declare the variable before the block itself, then it should work:

```
-(void) scan {
    Scanner *scanner = [[Scanner alloc] init];
    __block id scanComplete;
    scanComplete = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ScanComplete" 
                        object:scanner 
                        queue:nil 
                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
                           /*
                           do something
                           */
                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:scanComplete];
                           [scanner release];
                    }];
    [scanner startScan];
}
```

Comment: You need `__block id scanComplete;`, or it will be copied into the block and you will be leaking observers.

Comment: In the world of ARC, the comment on using `__block` to avoid capture no longer holds true. What _does_ hold true, is that the `__block` qualifier fixes a fundamental problem: when the block is defined, `addObserverForName:...` has not returned yet, so the value that is captured is `nil` at best (when running under ARC, because of its implicit auto-nil on variable declaration), or **undefined**, trading one BAD_ACCESS for completely undefined behavior, at worst…

Comment: Removing the observer by referring to a local variable from inside the block was always skanky. Store the returned observer token (here, `scanComplete`) as an instance variable; under ARC this should be a `__weak` instance variable to prevent a retain cycle on self.

Comment: @matt Why? What's skanky about wanting to completely localize the scope of all the moving parts involved with block-based notifications?

Comment: `[scanner release];` should be outside the block

Answer (score 15):

You should not unregister in the register block. Instead, store the token returned from `addObserverForName` (in this case, your `scanComplete`) as an instance variable or in a collection that is an instance variable, and unregister later when you're about to go out of existence (e.g. in `dealloc`). What I do is keep an NSMutableSet called `observers`. So:

```
id ob = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserverForName:@"whatever" object:nil queue:nil 
     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        // ... whatever ...
}];
[self->observers addObject:ob];
```

And then later:

```
for (id ob in self->observers)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:ob];
self->observers = nil;
```

Comment: If you want a one-shot notification, I don't see why you shouldn't be able unregister in the block itself.

Comment: Agreed with the above comment. I think whats missing from this answer is the "why". I think explaining why "you should not unregister in the register block" would be helpful. Especially since Apples own documentation for this API includes recommending unregistering in that block...

Comment: @DanielGalasko The question was how to prevent the crash, and my answer correctly states a way to do that. The accepted answer tackles the problem from the other end, the declaration of `ob`. Both answers are correct ways to prevent the crash.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Document about this method:

The following example shows how you can register to receive locale change notifications.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
self.localeChangeObserver = [center addObserverForName:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil
    queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

        NSLog(@"The user's locale changed to: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
    }];
```

To unregister observations, you pass the object returned by this method to removeObserver:. You **must** invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center removeObserver:self.localeChangeObserver];
```

Answer (score -4):

The scope of the block doesn't have permission to release the scanner object. If you're not using garbage collection, removing the `release` and making the scanner autorelease (`[[[Scanner alloc] init] autorelease]`) should do the trick.

You should also be able to safely move the call to `removeObserver` outside of the block.

For the case of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`: Entering `bt` in the console window after the application crashes will give you a backtrace, and should inform you where the error occurred.