# Retain cycles when using addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I am new to programming with block. I have following code (not using arc) in my Listener class:

```
- (void)someBlock:((void)^(NSDictionary *)myDictionary)myBlock
{
    __block Listener *weakSelf = self;
    weakSelf = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                   addObserverForName:@"MyNotification"
                               object:nil
                                queue:nil
                           usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
        { 
            //--- Here have the retain cycles
            myBlock(note.userInfo);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:weakSelf
                                                            name:@"MyNotification"];
        }];
}
```

and in my DoMyStuff class:

```
... some code
Listener *myListener = [[[Listener alloc] init] autorelease];
[myListener someBlock:((void)^(NSDictionary *)myDictionary)myBlock{
    [self.someProperty doSomething:myDictionary];
}];
```

Can anyone tell me the right direction to solve the retain cycles?
I have checked these two questions

1. ["Correct management of addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550798/correct-management-of-addobserverfornameobjectqueueusingblock)
2. ["Why doesn't Remove Observer from NSNotificationCenter:addObserverForName:usingBlock get called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477629/why-doesnt-remove-observer-from-nsnotificationcenteraddobserverfornameusingbl)

but they did not use block inside another block, so, the solutions there don't work for me.

Comment: my answer should probably help.

Comment: You should note that `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` does not return a reference to `self` but a pointer to an opaque object that acts as the observer.

Comment: what makes you think there's a retain cycle?

Comment: @newacct , there is `self` inside `myListener someBlock:` and this block is used by notification center's method and may live long enough to cause a 'leak'(maybe observer is never deregistered?). And block is holding self. The proble is with `DoMyStuff` class I think.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the comments. But did you guys actually run this on the real project? I have tried all the possibilities I could imagine today, none of them worked. I tried to track the observer itself in memory, then I found a very funny thing. I used a property to replace self as the observer, then I put the breakpoints to observer. I actually found, the observer memory location changed after [... addobserverForName ...]. I am really appreciate your time, but I think the question itself might be harder than we think.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried to remove the observer in dealloc with no luck. Dealloc and removeobserver function got called, but when I tried to post the notification, the 

notification center still tried to post the message to  released observer which caused bad excess. I think the reason is the observer has been released, but the notification 

center did not remove it.

Comment: I have tried to create my own classes to do this "double blocks", no retain cycles, no memory leaks, and all deallocs got called as expected. This only happened when I tried to use "addObserverForName", I think the only place I could removeobserver is inside the block. I also check this article http://tumblr.alanquatermain.me/post/1686415314/an-nsnotification-blocks-gotcha and I think it lead me to the right direction, but for the last solution, it did not remove the observer from the center.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov: "there is self inside myListener someBlock:" Yes, so that block has a reference to `self`. But there is no cycle -- there is no reference from `self` to that block.

Comment: @newacct , Yes, but that block with captured self is captured by `addObserver:...` inside notification block and depending on other code(and on removing obeservers) may leak.
Also there is nice article http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsnotificationcenter-with-blocks-considered-harmful/

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov: Of course you have to remove observers when you add them. That's not a leak. The OP's code indeed removes the observer when the notification is received for the firs time. The notification block needs to retain the DoMyStuff object because it needs to perform an operation on it when the notification is received. This is all correct. I see no leak, nor retain cycles, from the code the OP has shown.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you are using `[self.someProperty doSomething:myDictionary];` inside block thus retaining self. Note that using ivars will lead to retain cycles as it's the same as self->ivar.

Usually it looks like this (__weak/__unsafe_unretained is for ARC, __block for MRR)

```
__weak ClassName *weakSelf = self;
[SomeClass someMethodWithBlock:^{
    // use weakSelf here; if you want to make sure that self is alive throughout whole block, do something like ClassName *strongSelf = weakSelf;
}];
```

There is nice library https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc which has @weakify/@strongify macroses for this(probably ARC only).

Also you should use ARC if possible(it is available from iOS 4, if I remember correctly and has __weak from iOS 5, which should be fine these days).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried this, but it did not work for my case. I have put some comments for op.